# Php set variable property default value not working in php 7.1

Tags: php

I have a variable property set default value array, it works in my php 5.6 localhost but not working when i upload to server with php 7.1 , can anyone tell me why?

```
class foo {
    var $bar = array();

    function baz($data) {
        $this->bar['data'] = $data; <---- works in php 5.6, not working in php 7.1
    }
}
```

in php 7.1, I have to update variable property in construct

```
function __construct(){
    $this->bar = array();
}
```

Comment: is it because I use this class inside of trait?

Comment: what's information in php error log?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided produces very same result from PHP version 7.1.25 to 7.3.2 (check on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BYfYm)):

```
object(foo)#1 (1) {
  ["bar"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["data"]=>
    int(22)
  }
}
```

Even it works, I would suggest ALWAYS initializing class properties in `__construct` as you discovered too:

```
function __construct(){
    $this->bar = array();
}
```

more importantly, prefer using one of `public`/`protected` or `private` [visibility modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), rather than `var` which turns into a `public` under the hood.